# How can force a route change from javascript when using `<app-location>`

Tags: polymer

I am moving over to using `<app-location>` and `<app-route>` for my navigation in my Polymer app.  I require my users to login first (if they haven't already) which is done outside the scope of routing. So once logged in, or if they were already logged in, the app will start on the page entered in the browser url bar.

I have a scenario where its the first time the user has attempted to login, and so will need to be redirected to a different page to fill in their profile.  What I would like to do programatically from javascript is push a new url at the application so they are redirected to a profile page after logon, and then have the profile page simulate the browser back button to return to the originally entered starting page.

How do I do that in a compatible way with `<app-location>`, assuming I am NOT using # routing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two way binding between `<app-location>` and `<app-route>` you can simply change the `data` property of your `<app-route>` to profile for example.

So for example if your setup looks something like this:

```
  <app-location route="{{route}}"  id="appLocation" use-hash-as-path></app-location>
  <app-route id="appRoute"
        route="{{route}}"
        pattern="/:page"
        data="{{page}}"
        tail="{{tail}}">
  </app-route>
```

You can do something like this:

```
this.$.appRoute.data = {page:'profile'}
```

Or if you  `page` is a property that is bound in your element/app you can simply update the `page` property which in turn will update the `data` property of your `<app-route>` element and eventually the `route` property of your `<app-location>` element through the data-binding system.

Comment: I assume you meant to say something more about changing the property `this.page` as an alternative.  You don't say anything about simulating the browser back button, can I just do `window.history.back()`?

Comment: Yeah thanks, I updated the answer to complete the sentence. 

Depends on what the behavior should be. If you do it the way I outlined then if the user clicks on the browser back button it will navigate back to the profile page. If you don't want that you can use `window.history.back()` or alternatively use `window.history.replaceState()`.